# Recreate activity after user give all permissions to the app?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

I need user to give 2 permissions to the app. In the first run, after user give the permissions I'd like to recreate() my activity.

I'm doing it:

```
    private final String [] permissions = {
            "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO",
            "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
    };
```

and:

```
        int requestCode = 200;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode);
        }
```

So after user gives record_audio and read_phone_state permissions I'd like to recreate() my activity.

I try:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            recreate();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error, give the permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
```

The problem is, it is like a loop, recreating the activity all time not only the time after user give both permissions. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are always calling `requestPermission`, because you are not checking if the user already approved your permission on his device. So, first, you need to check if that particular permission is allowed, if it is you continue your path, if not, call `requestPermission`.

To check for a permission use this:

```
        //CHECKING IF PHONE CALL PERMISSION IS ALLOWED
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(IntroActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(IntroActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, REQUEST_PHONE_CALL);
        }
```

This will check if permission `CALL_PHONE` is allowed on the device for this app. If it isn't, then it will call `requestPermission` with `REQUEST_PHONE_CALL` code, in your case, it's `200`. If it is approved then it won't call `requestPermission` and will continue further.

After `requestPermission` is called, your `onRequestPermissionResult` is called. There you can use your `recreate()` function and after the activity is recreated it should continue without calling `requestPermission`. Just change permissions in my code to match yours, so instead of `CALL_PHONE` you'll have `READ_PHONE_STATE`. A good thing would be to check for each permission so you can see if the user declined one of them, which can happen.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should check if your app already has the two permissions before requesting them. This way you'll be able to recreate your activity only the first time and you'll not fall into a loop.
In code:

```kotlin
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(permissions[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED || checkSelfPermission(
                    permissions[1]
                ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
            ) {
                requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Oh, that is what I need. Thanks a lot.

Comment: my pleasure :) :)

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi please next time check if there is already a similar answer to the question. If it is and you think it could be better then provide your "upgrade" in the comments of the answer. This way we won't have so many same answers in one thread. Since I already posted exactly this 5 minutes before you answered.

Comment: @SlothCoding I was writing my answer right when you was, user found mine useful to, so what's this about? As you can see, in addition my answer is slightly different from yours because is using the permission array provided by the user. I can't find any "upgrade" guideline on stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Save a state in which you set when the activity is recreated and whether you have accepted permissions. By doing so, if the activity has already been recreated and the permissions have already been accepted, you will not recreate the activity.